# How to format batch file output with line separators

Tags: windows, batch-file

Maybe I'm just unaware of the correct terminology to search for, but I have a batch file with a bunch of diagnostic commands in it (ipconfig, netstat, tracert, etc...) that, when a user is unable to connect to a file share, I have them double-click this batch file to gather information from their Windows computer.

All of these commands output to one file using the >> to append each command.

Problem is, this text file gets pretty long and messy. All I want to do is separate each commands output with something visually pleasing to the eye, like:

===========================================================

**IPCONFIG**

===========================================================

...the contents of ipconfig will be here

===========================================================

**NETSTAT**

===========================================================

...the contents of netstat will be here

**How do I add characters like the = symbol?**

Thanks!

### **My batch file contents:**

```
time /T > %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
nltest /dnsgetdc:domain.com >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
nltest /dclist:domain.com >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
nltest /dclist:domain >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ipconfig /all >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
tracert Server01 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
nslookup Server01 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping Server01 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
pathping Server01 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping Server02 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping Server03 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping Server04 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping Server05 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping google.com >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping abc.com >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
ping 4.2.2.2 >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
netstat >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
route print >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
netsh advfirewall show allprofiles >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
gpresult /Scope User /v >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
gpresult /Scope Computer /v >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
systeminfo >> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt
```

Comment: What has this to do with `REM`? Just do this: `echo =====>> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Server01_diag.txt"`

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familiar with the terminology. I did try your suggestion before posting and it didn't work the first few times. I should have kept trying, as that worked for me. THANKS!

Comment: You might want to do something like this so that all of your separator lines are the same length.    set Bar================================ and then     echo(%Bar%

Comment: You're welcome! It's rather confusing as you mention `REM` in the title, but it does not appear in your actual question at all...

Comment: :check: -- updated the title to something a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

This batch is less redundant and will frame all output with a bar containing date and time.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Bar============================================================"
> %userprofile%\desktop\Server01_diag.txt (
  For %%A in (
    "nltest /dnsgetdc:domain.com "
    "nltest /dclist:domain.com "
    "nltest /dclist:domain "
    "ipconfig /all "
    "tracert Server01 "
    "nslookup Server01 "
    "ping Server01 "
    "pathping Server01 "
    "ping Server02 "
    "ping Server03 "
    "ping Server04 "
    "ping Server05 "
    "ping google.com "
    "ping abc.com "
    "ping 4.2.2.2 "
    "netstat "
    "route print "
    "netsh advfirewall show allprofiles "
    "gpresult /Scope User /v "
    "gpresult /Scope Computer /v "
    "systeminfo "
  ) Do Echo ==!date!==!time!%Bar%&%%~A
  Echo ==!date!==!time!%Bar%
)
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks LotPings. Your answer reminds me of when I used to work I.T. for a company... INTERNALLY, meaning I was allowed to focus. Now I work in the MSP model which means I'm currently being whored out to whatever company pays the most, and even my farts need to be billable.... and don't have time to fine tune things like this (aka have fun). Haha... :)